# Pthread blocking / updatable timer

Tags: c++, timer, pthreads, sleep, blocking

I am currently using pthreads and I have a run() method in one of my threads. The run() method checks the first element of a vector for a start time and needs to do a blocking sleep until that time is reached, allowing other threads to execute. The problem is that the front element of the vector can update and I will need to reset the timer in my run() method. I am not really sure how to approach this issue. I can't use sleep since it will wait until the start time it last check which may have been updated to an earlier time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pthread_kill() to wake a particular thread that is sleeping at sigtimedwait().

```
sigset_t _fSigMask; // global sigmask
```

We do this before creating our threads.  Threads inherit their signal mask from the thread that creates them.  We use SIGUSR1 to signal our threads.  Other signals are available.

```
sigemptyset(&_fSigMask);
sigaddset(&_fSigMask, SIGUSR1);
sigaddset(&_fSigMask, SIGSEGV);
```

Then to sleep a thread:

```
int nSig;
struct timespec tmTimeout = { nSec, nNanoSec }; // from your vector of times
sigtimedwait(&fSigMask, &nSig, &tmTimeout);
```

Then to wake the thread, pThread, just signal it:

```
pthread_kill(pThread, SIGUSR1);
```

By the way, during our testing, sleeping and waking our threads this way was many times faster than using condition variables.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is updating the vector is going to need to signal the sleeping thread one way or another.  There are a dozen ways to do this but two obvious ones are condition variables or just using select with a pipe or similar.

With condition variables you can used `pthread_cond_timedwait` with your calculated timeout value.  If it times out, fine.  If you get signaled you have to read the vector, recalculate the timeout, and block again.

Similarly with `select()` you calculate and use the timeout value from the vector and block while waiting for a timeout or some input on the pipe.  Whatever is updating the vector also writes something to the pipe and the thread wakes up, recalculates, and so on...